# How to edit an entity when i edit an other entity

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I've a ManyToMany relation between Projects and Organizations table in Cakephp.

When i archived an Organization i want archived all projects associated.

I've test to implement an entity method (archive()) but i can't access to organization because CakePHP use an ORM. So what's the solution ?

Create private controller seem be discourage.
Entity doesn't have access necessary.

I can not find the right design

Thx!

Comment: Why not a table method? Also, if you have a many to many, one of those projects could have more than one organization. In that case, you would be archiving the project across all organizations if you archived just one organization and all its projects.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I need to check if each project have an other organization not archived for the moment.

So for you it's a table method? You've an example of use?